# Transfer large data from Android Activity to WebView Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, data-transfer

I know there were a lot of related posts, but non of them contains clear answer how it would be possible to transfer huge data from Android to JS or vice versa. The problem is when I try to do that, on the JS side the string is cut and it is not complete. After this line I get only part of the string on Javascript side

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + jsToExecute, null);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript: " + jsToExecute);
}
```

What could be a possible solution for this?

Thanks in advance for the answers or for the ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to save the data into a temporary file and then read the data using File plugin. But not sure if this have any limitations.

Or you can create own JS function that will return the data:

```
//this is an Activity
this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJsHandler(this), "myHandler");

private class MyJsHandler {

    private CordovaActivity activity;

    public MyJsHandler(CordovaActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getData() {
        if (this.activity.data) {
            return this.activity.data;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
var data = window.myHandler.getData();
```

Comment: I've tried the second version to call Java from JS to retrieve some data, didn't have limitations as had the opposite way. Concerning to the file, not sure about performance. Anyway thank you for the idea.

Comment: So many years later and this answer is still useful. [myWebView.evaluateJavascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080696/webview-evaluatejavascript-apparently-just-not-running-for-long-strings) also has a limitation apparently on how much data you can send